# Is there any way to get Class from reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any way to get Class from  reflection? 
What i want to do is, I have implemented custom Serializer for hazelcast-3.2.3. and I don't want to write separate Serializer for each class(whom object I need to store in Hcast).

I want this

```
class TestSerializer<T> {
 Class<T> classType;
 Public Test(){
  classType = T.someway() //if there is any method to get that;
}

}
```

Because I'm configuring my Serializer in `hazelcast.xml` i cant pass `Class` in constructor parameters.

Comment: I'm not creating its object in code. 
I'm configuring in .xml file. HazelCast call it, and hcast expect default/non-parameter constructor.

Comment: Cant you use generics with `<T extends SomeInterface>` where you create `SomeInterface` with the method you want to call ?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're really asking how to get the class *of the generic type T* during runtime, not just a class.

The easiest way to do it is to pass it as an argument to the constructor but if you really, **really** want to do it with reflection, you can use a trick that eg. Jackson uses which relies on anonymous sub classes. To do this, read up on how [`TypeReference`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java) works, especially [Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.fi/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html)

I might, of course, be wildly off here on what you want to do. Please correct me if I am :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `TestSerializer` cannot get that type internally due to type erasure. That information has to be provided externally.

This means you'll have to refactor how you do it through configuration.